# Converting Pandas Dataframe to Numpy array with to_numpy() doesn't change my output at all

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to write a function that converts the following dataframe to a numpy array but the output is not changing to an array, can someone assist? Please find the input dataframe, my code, my output and expected output below:

Function parameters:
Should take a str as input and return a numpy array type as output.
The array should only have two columns containing the year and the population, in other words, it should have a shape (?, 2) where ? is the length of the data.
The values within the array should be of type int.

[joined_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHqni.png)
my code:

```
def year_pop(country_name):
    return get_years
```

Input:

```
year_pop('Aruba')
```

Expected output:

```
array([[  1960,  54211],
       [  1961,  55438],
       [  1962,  56225],
        ...
       [  2016, 104822],
       [  2017, 105264]])
```

[My output after code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzXQp.png)

Comment: you can return `get_years.to_numpy(dtype=int)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_numpy` method does not work inplace, so you need to assign the result to `get_years` to overwrite the dataframe with the numpy array:

```
get_years = get_years.to_numpy(dtype=int)
```

If you want to reshape it as in the expected output:

```
get_years = get_years.T.reset_index().to_numpy(dtype=int)
```

Comment: That works, thank you. How can i reshape as stated here:

The array should only have two columns containing the year and the population, in other words, it should have a shape (?, 2) where ? is the length of the data.

Comment: I don't know your data. try reshape as in my edit: `.reshape(-1,2)`. If the expected output is not want you want try `.reshape(2,-1).T` instead. Otherwise `print(get_years)` before the `return` and show me. If this solution solves your task pleas accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Getting somewhere :) Looks like this now.

    array([[ 54211,  55438],
           [ 56225,  56695],
           [ 57032,  57360]

What i need it to look like: (where '1960' is the column name and 54211 the pop that year)

    array([[  1960,  54211],
           [  1961,  55438],
           [  1962,  56225]

Comment: ok got it. years are the columns of your df. so in the last line of the function you need: `get_years = get_years.T.reset_index().to_numpy(dtype=int)`

Comment: You welcome :) Please accept the answer if you have no other problems.

Comment: I am not allowed to do that yet. I tried to upvote you:) Account still new.

Comment: ok. got it :) You just need to click the checkmark as in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

PS welcome to stackoverflow community !